# Monadicity and sheaves.

Tags: ct.category-theory

Is the inclusion of the category of sheaves into the category of presheaves monadic? If not, then maybe it preserves directed colimits?

Comment: Ok. I think the answer is no. Sorry for disturbing.

Comment: The answer to the second question is "not in general", but it is true that it will always be *accessible*, i.e. preserve sufficiently-highly-filtered colimits.  For some purposes that is good enough.


Answer (score 5):

The answer (to the first question) is yes: [reflections](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/reflective+subcategory) are always monadic, and the associated monad is [idempotent](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/idempotent+monad).

Comment: Thanks. It is nice to know such general result. I still think that the answer for second question is no. 